# python 3x listbox contents from tuple not displaying on seperate lines but repeated every line

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, tuples

my code creates a listbox and displays the contents of a tuple so that i can select an item, trouble is the listbox just shows the complete tuple on every line, rather than each tuple item per line, i'm sure its just syntax but cannot see it ? here is a code snippet that creates the tuple and the listbox can anyone see where i have gone wrong ?

```
    def mysqlConnect():
     import pymysql
     sqlUsr = MysqlUsr.get()
     sqlpwd = Mysqlpwd.get()
     conn = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.27', user= sqlUsr, passwd=sqlpwd, db='information_schema')
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM SCHEMATA")
     schema_names = cursor.fetchall()
     schema_tuple = tuple(schema_names)
     countrynames = (schema_tuple)
     cnames = (countrynames)
     for item in schema_names:
         lbox.insert(END, schema_names)
    # create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
     yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(command=lbox.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
     yscroll.grid(row=15, column=3, sticky='ns')
     lbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
     lbox.bind('<Double-1>', connectStatus)
     mainframe.bind('<Return>', connectStatus)


   # Set the starting state of the interface, including selecting the
   # default gift to send, and clearing the messages.  Select the first
   # country in the list; because the <<ListboxSelect>> event is only
   # generated when the user makes a change, we explicitly call showPopulation.
     gift.set('dbconnect')
     sentmsg.set('')
     statusmsg.set('')
     lbox.selection_set(0)
     conn.close()

    def connectStatus(*args):
        idxs = lbox.curselection()
        if len(idxs)==1:
            idx = int(idxs[0])
        lbox.see(idx)
        name = countrynames[idx]

    usertxt=Label(mainframe, text="User =")
    userlabel=Label(mainframe,text=usr)
    pathlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Project directory path is P:\\Projects_2013\\") 
    projectdetaillabel=Label(mainframe, text="Project detail:")
    enternewname=Label(mainframe, text="Enter NEW project name:")
    ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable= assetVar).grid(column=4, row=2,columnspan=2, sticky=(W,E))
    createbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="Create Folders", command=genAsset)
    selectlabel=Label (mainframe, text='Select an existing project:')
    browsebutton=Button(mainframe, width= 18,text="Browse", command=sel_Browse)
    prjtnm = Entry(mainframe, width=50)
    optionlabel=Label (mainframe, text="Project options:")
    completedbutton=Button(mainframe, text="Mark as completed", command=fldrRename)
    openbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="Open Directory",   command=Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Dir)
    shortcutlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Program Shortcuts:")
    xenonbutton=Button(mainframe, image=xenonimage, command=opn_xenon)
    wdebutton=Button(mainframe, image=webdateimage, command=opn_data_extr)
    wcebutton=Button(mainframe, image=webcontimage, command=opn_content_extr)
    htbutton=Button(mainframe, image=htimage, command=opn_ht)
    mysqllabel=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql:")
    mysqlbutton=Button(mainframe, width=18,text="MySql connect:",command=mysqlConnect)
    mysqlusr=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql Username:")
    mysqlusrentry=Entry(mainframe, width=18,textvariable= MysqlUsr)
    mysqlpasswordlabel=Label(mainframe, text="Mysql Password:")
    mysqlpwdentry=Entry(mainframe, width=18,textvariable= Mysqlpwd)
    lbox = Listbox(mainframe, listvariable=cnames, height=10)
    g0=Label(mainframe, text="Select Database")
    g1=Label(mainframe, text="Option:")
    g2=Radiobutton(mainframe, text=commands['dbconnect'], variable=gift, value='dbconnect')
    g3=Radiobutton(mainframe, text=commands['dbdelete'], variable=gift, value='dbdelete')
    send=Button(mainframe, text='Apply', command=(connectStatus), default='active')
    sentlbl=Label(mainframe, textvariable=sentmsg, anchor='center')
    status=Label(mainframe, textvariable=statusmsg, anchor=W)


    #grid all the above
    usertxt.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
    userlabel.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    pathlabel.grid(column=4, columnspan=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    projectdetaillabel.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
    enternewname.grid(column=2, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky=E, pady=15)
    lbox.grid(column=3, row=15, rowspan=6, columnspan=3, sticky=(N,S,E,W))
    prjtnm.grid(row=3,column=4, columnspan=2)
    createbutton.grid(column=6, row=2, sticky=E, padx=10)
    selectlabel.grid(column=2,row=3,columnspan=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
    browsebutton.grid(row=3,column=6, sticky=W, padx=10)
    optionlabel.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=E)
    completedbutton.grid(row=4,column=4, sticky=W, padx=2)
    openbutton.grid(row=4,column=5, sticky=E, padx=2)
    shortcutlabel.grid(column=1, row=6,sticky=E, pady=60)
    xenonbutton.grid(row=6, column=3,sticky=E,)
    wdebutton.grid(row=6, column=4)
    wcebutton.grid(row=6, column=5)
    htbutton.grid(row=6,column=6,sticky=W,)
    mysqllabel.grid(column=1, row=8,sticky=E, pady=20)
    mysqlbutton.grid(row=8, column=6, sticky=E, padx=10)
    mysqlusr.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=E)
    mysqlusrentry.grid(row=8, column=3, sticky=W)
    mysqlpasswordlabel.grid(row=8, column=4, sticky=E)
    mysqlpwdentry.grid(row=8, column=5, sticky=W)
    g0.grid(column=3, row=14, sticky=W)
    g1.grid(column=4, row=14, sticky=W)
    g2.grid(column=6, row=16, sticky=W, padx=20, pady=10);
    g3.grid(column=6, row=17, sticky=W, padx=20);
    send.grid(column=6, row=16, sticky=E)
    sentlbl.grid(column=3, row=22, columnspan=2, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5);
    status.grid(column=4, row=23, columnspan=2, sticky=(W,E));
```

Comment: Can you please correct the indentation of your post? It is unclear where functions start and end.

Comment: Yes, problem; your indentation is not consistent. Please indent the code so it'd work *in Python*.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for help on how to copy and paste your code and format it  correctly. Don't indent it all by hand.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that runs only with Tkinter? When you construct this program the solution may already become clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this code:

```
 for item in schema_names:
     lbox.insert(END, schema_names)
```

Have you tried using `item` instead of `schema_names` in the insert statement?

```
 for item in schema_names:
     lbox.insert(END, item)
```

Assuming that `schema_names` is a tuple, you can also replace the loop with this single line:

```
lbox.insert(END, *schema_names)
```

Comment: Thank you @bryan Oakley, both of your suggestions work, it appears that i was missing the '*' from when i tried the single line hence trying the loop, but then misunderstood 'item' thinking it meant the name of item i was using.   thank you